# In my nextjs website, route change by clicking link is huge but i didn't use server side rendering

Tags: performance, next.js, routes, loading

when reloading page its very faster, but when changing routes by clicking any link its taking huge time to render. sometimes a Server side api is calling and success in 800ms. but after success my api call its taking more 6/7 seconds to render the ui

I want to find the reason

Comment: You should add a loading states so navigation feels smooth between pages.

Comment: I already have a loading state to indicate that route is changing. but loading time is huge without any reason

https://6valley-react.6amtech.com/

this is my app link. can you please check

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what pages are loading slow?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was I forgot to add `prefetch={false}` to some  component, so Next.js will prefetch all links which is the reason it loads slower.

So please consider yourself if some links are not necessarily to be prefetched, just add `<Link prefetch={false} />` and see if it works.

Docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link#prefetch